# Query on matplotlib ticker module

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html
says

> ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

what is ax? and if it's a pyplot object as I understand from

> ax.plot(np.arange(2000, 2010), range(10))

than why for me it says:

```
    In [107]: ax.get_xaxis
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-107-7bca17863338> in <module>()
    ----> 1 ax.get_xaxis

    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_xaxis'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code that should be written there:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(np.arange(2000, 2010), range(10))
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.show()
```